# Equalizer for darkice and icecast

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, stream, equalizer, icecast

By installing Darkice in combination with Icecast and my USB audio card, it is possible to stream the output of my vinyl player to my Sonos system. I have followed this guide https://www.instructables.com/Add-Aux-to-Sonos-Using-Raspberry-Pi/.

Now is there a way I can use an **equalizer** in between, to reduce the treble and increase the bass? I've tried to install the libasound equalizer plugin:
`sudo apt-get install -y libasound2-plugin-equal`
according to this form post: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=72008

Though, the icecast stream stayes uneffected by the changes I make in the equalizer.

Comment: I'm no expert, but...  Are you running direct from ALSA to Darkice?  I'm interested in the topic, although I don't have sonos.I also assume that you are running something like alsamixer to control the mixer?

Comment: Additionally, if would be good to refer to the version of Ubuntu that you are running on your raspberry.